# How would I get the sum of a column where another column is equal to a specific value?

Tags: python, sqlite

If I had something like the table below on a sqlite DB, would it be possible to get he sum of xp of ID 1, 2 ... etc?

```
ID  | XP
1     10  
1     47
1     3
1     1
2     48
4     39
5     22
5     48
```

example

```
1 = 61
2 = 48
4 = 39
5 = 60
```

Comment: Use **GROUP BY** and **HAVING**.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? something like
`SELECT id, xp FROM table GROUP BY xp HAVING user_id=user_id` ?

Comment: First, you have to group by **id** and not **xp** as answered by @rudolfovic because you want to group all same id into one. And when you use **GROUP BY**, you should not use other columns in select query, but you can use any aggregate function like **sum(XP)** in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just execute `select ID, sum(XP) from data group by ID`

Comment: yeah, it wouldn't let me at the time, I just had to do something and just got back. :3